# My if statement is false but it does print the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, printing, conditional-statements

```
x = 5
print('Before 5')
if x > 5:
    print('Is 5')
    print('Is still 5')
    print('Third 5')
    print('Afterwards 5')
    print('Before 6')
if x == 6:
    print('Is 6')
    print('Is still 6')
    print('Third 6')
print('Afterwards 6')
```

so the beginning its wrong I'm expecting to print only Print('Before 5')print('Afterwards 5') and print('Before 6')
but it doesnt, only prints the print('Before 5') and stops. Also I tried by deleting the space so they are not on the same line with true statement and this is my result:

line 9 if x == 6:
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Im learning by myself and this is my first time learning a programming language, its so fun but im having a hard time solving this :D Thank you.

Comment: All the lines between `if x > 5:` and `if x == 6:` are indented so they are part of the `if x > 5:` if-statement. If that is not what you intended, then adjust the indentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try elif: instead of if: --- it should work that way

Comment: Also don't give up, you are doing great! It's so challenging but very rewarding to learn Python. I'm also learning, just started a couple of months ago!

Comment: Thank you so much, im so worried if this might be like waste of time for me to learn because im so bad math so i feel like theres no point of learning because i feel like im not gonna improve XD but im trying, Thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

It stops because:
x is not greater than 5 so it skips the first if.
x is not 6 so it skips the second if.
It prints everything that is out of the two if blocks.
That's why it only prints `Before 5` and `Afterwards 6`

I think you want this:

```
x = 5
print('Before 5')
if x > 5:
    print('Is 5')
    print('Is still 5')
    print('Third 5')
print('Afterwards 5')
print('Before 6')
if x == 6:
    print('Is 6')
    print('Is still 6')
    print('Third 6')
print('Afterwards 6')
```

Comment: so how can i make it print the Print('afterwards 5') and print('before 6') because those are the one that im trying to make it if is not equal then print afterwards 5 and before 6 idk if you get im saying, sorry with my bad english

Comment: I am not sure I understand but maybe you want this:

x = 5
print('Before 5')
if x > 5:
    print('Is 5')
    print('Is still 5')
    print('Third 5')
print('Afterwards 5')
print('Before 6')
if x == 6:
    print('Is 6')
    print('Is still 6')
    print('Third 6')
print('Afterwards 6')

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the indent on 'print('Afterwards 5') and print('Before 6').
So if i understood you problem right, then this is the solution

```
x = 5

print('Before 5')

if x > 5:
    print('Is 5')
    print('Is still 5')
    print('Third 5')

print('Afterwards 5')
print('Before 6')

if x == 6:
    print('Is 6')
    print('Is still 6')
    print('Third 6')

print('Afterwards 6')
```